# angucomplete-alt issue getting data from remote url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-directive

I am using the angucomplete-alt directive to make an autocomplete list from a get request.

When I use the github api

```
<div angucomplete-alt id="ex5" placeholder="Search projects" pause="500" selected-object="selectedProject" remote-url="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" remote-url-data-field="items" search-fields="name" title-field="name" minlength="2" input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight"></div>
```

it returns results with no problems.

When I try and use jsonplaceholder sample api

```
<div angucomplete-alt id="ex5" placeholder="Search posts" pause="500" selected-object="selectedProject" remote-url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" search-fields="id" title-field="title" minlength="1" input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight"></div>
```

I am not able to return results, however when I look in the console it is loading the content (sample input 22) but I can't get anything to appear in the auto complete list.

The only difference I can see is the structure.  I have removed remote-url-data-field="items" from the jsonplaceholder, I am not getting any errors, what might I be doing wrong here?

Working github example commented out.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBfog

```
    <html class="no-js" id="ng-app" ng-app="app">
      <head>
        <title>Angucomplete Alt: Autocomplete Directive for AngularJS</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>
      </head>
      <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <div>
          <div class="large-padded-row">
            <div class="padded-row">
    <!--
              <div angucomplete-alt id="ex5" placeholder="Search projects" pause="500" selected-object="selectedProject" remote-url="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" remote-url-data-field="items" search-fields="name" title-field="name" minlength="2" input-class="form-control form-control-small"
            match-class="highlight"></div>
    -->
              <div angucomplete-alt id="ex5" placeholder="Search posts" pause="500" selected-object="selectedProject" remote-url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" search-fields="id" title-field="title" minlength="1" input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="result">
              <div class="" ng-show="selectedProject">
                Repository: <span class="bold-span">{{selectedProject.originalObject.git_url}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angucomplete-alt.js"></script>
        <script>
          var app = angular.module('app', ["ngTouch", "angucomplete-alt"]);

          app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http',
            function MainController($scope, $http) {
            }
          ]); 
          </script>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response from jsonplaceholder does not have a root object. That's is why. Angucomplete-alt does not support JSON object without root object.

Comment: Thanks for this info I will make sure my real data structure complies.